# DirectConsumerNotAvailableException using endpointUri

Tags: apache-camel

> org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException:
>   No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://start]

I get error above when I try the following code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    ConsumerTemplate consumer = context.createConsumerTemplate();
    consumer.start();
    String response = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
    template.sendBody("direct:start", response);
    Exchange out = consumer.receive("direct:start");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    consumer.stop();
}
```

but works when tried as below

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    final DataFormat dataFormat = new BindyCsvDataFormat(TTlabsResponse.class);

    RouteBuilder rb = new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("file://src/test/resources?noop=true&fileName=tsv.txt")
            .unmarshal(dataFormat).process(new SimpleProcessor());
        }
    };
    context.addRoutes(rb);
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    context.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first you do not have a route that consumes from the `direct:start` endpoint and why you get an error when you try to send a message to a `direct` endpoint which has no consumer.

The direct endpoint is like a direct method invocation and requires a consumer.

You can send the `seda` instead which is using a queue to decouple the producer and the consumer.

See more at

- http://camel.apache.org/direct
- http://camel.apache.org/seda

Comment: The file to be read is on a samba share hence the  reason to use template.sendBody("direct:start", response); I am looking for the simplest way to unmarshal the payload and process using Processor.

Comment: After reading http://camel.apache.org/routes.html, i will try from("direct:start").process(new SimpleProcessor());